# How to set a custom mouse cursor for external application window?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, cursor, unity-game-engine

I have "process_name.exe" and want to set a custom cursor for main window of that process (which is NOT a .net managed application).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please do not include tags in the title of your questions.  And, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried to search, but all I found is using system.windows.forms.cursor class or form.cursor property. They can be used only for setting a custom cursor for current application.
I know I need to use some windows api functions for this. I want to know what functions would help me and how to apply them.

Comment: It's possible, you need to use a windows hook.  You cannot write that code in C#, a language like C is required to write a DLL that can be injected into the process you want to mess with.  Best thing to do here is focus on writing your own programs first and learn more about Windows programming.  So you can ask an answerable question with the proper [tag].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity 4 is going to have hardware cursor support (available in the Unity 4 beta right now), so if you can wait around for that, don't worry about 3.5 software cursor issues too much.

From http://unity3d.com/unity/beta/notes:

> - New Cursor API was introduced:
>
>   - Cursor API supports both software and hardware cursors.
>   - Support for hardware cursors on the following platforms: Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, Flash.
>   - Configure the default cursor in your projects’ Player Settings.

Or if you need a solution rightaway, I believe there is a hardware cursor script being sold in the Unity Asset Store currently.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change another application's cursor. Each application controls its cursor. Imagine if somebody went around changing your application's cursor.

Comment: It is actually possible if you use some Windows API call.

Comment: I know it's possible because I've heared about c++ applications which do the same (but their source code is not accessable).

I need it for unity3d game (in unity3d there are no ways to set a custom hardware cursor).

Comment: Alvin Wong, I know this. And my question is what calls I need to use and how to use them in c#?

Comment: Don't t do it. The techniques they use are unsupported. Your customers will not be happy when your program stops working or causes the other program to crash.

Comment: Oops. Possible I've mistaked when supposed that their c++ applications set a cursor from another process. I don't now exactly how it works but I know that they can set a custom hardware cursor in Unity. I'll try to find a way to do the same from unity process by loading "presentationCore" assembly dynamically.